# HQL - Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate 4.3

I have OneToMany **Commande** --> **Article**

I want to delete **Commande** related to one **Article**.
first of all i try to select the desired list of **Commande**.

```
        Query querydeleteCmd = em.createQuery("select c from Commande c where (:art) in elements(c.articles)");
        querydeleteCmd.setParameter("art", new Article(1));
        List<Commande> commandes = querydeleteCmd.getResultList();
        commandes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This works fine, but when I want to delete (it's almost the same query) :

```
        Query querydeleteCmd = em.createQuery("delete from Commande c where (:art) in elements(c.articles)");
        querydeleteCmd.setParameter("art", new Article(1));
        querydeleteCmd.executeUpdate();
```

This gives me :

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'Commande_Article' is
>   specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate
>   source for data

Comment: care to tell people what you think is "IN ELEMENTS" ? `IN` is a JPQL keyword. There is no "ELEMENTS".

Comment: in elements exists in HQL : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: In which case the question is NOT JPA

Comment: you're right, i update the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception says:

> Table 'Commande_Article' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

And it's due to the fact that you are using `c.articles` as a source/collection of data for `in` clause of `where`, this is not possible because here `c` is in the same time the target of the `DELETE` operation and the source of data for `in` clause, which is confusing in the query.

As you already did you need to pass the collection of `articles` as a parameter without referencing `c` in the `where` clause to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand :
The problem is that I cannot specify something that I want to delete in the clause `"where"`.

```
delete from Commande c where (:art) in elements(c.articles)
```

So here I cannot use the `"c"` in the clause `"where"`

This is what I have done and it works very well :

1) I select a list of Commande to be deleted

```
Query querydeleteCmd = em.createQuery("select c from Commande c where (:art) in elements(c.articles)");
querydeleteCmd.setParameter("art", new Article(1));
List<Commande> commandes = querydeleteCmd.getResultList();
```

2) Then I delete all Commande using the result of the first query :

```
    Query queryDeleteCommande = em.createQuery("delete from Commande c where c in (:commandes)");
    queryDeleteCommande.setParameter("commandes", commandes);
    int countDeletedCommandes= queryDeleteCommande.executeUpdate();
```

Probably, there is better way to do it in one shot.